# Teach Rails 3 to talk to Amazon Redshift - permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, amazon-redshift

### Background

I just spun up a new Redshift instance on AWS and I can connect to it via the `psql` cli client without a problem.

### The Problem

I'm trying to get my Rails 3 app to connect to the Redshift box. I have the `pg` gem and the correct adapters. My `database.yml` file has the following details:

```
redshift_development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_name
  port: 5439
  pool: 5
  schema_search_path: schema_name
  username: my_uname
  password: password
  host: host
```

I manually created a table on the box called `cellphones`, and a model in my app `app/models/cellphone.rb`:

```
class Cellphone < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection 'redshift_development'
end
```

When I try to load in the app in the rails console and call `Cellphone`, I get the following error message:

```
[1] pry(main)> Cellphone
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  must be superuser to examine "client_min_messages"
: SHOW client_min_messages
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to ""
: SET client_min_messages TO ''
=> #<Devise::Models:0x3feef95050b4>
```

### The Really Weird Part

I'm already logged in as the superuser.

```
psql=# \c
psql (9.4.0, server 8.0.2)
SSL connection (<unimportant stuff>)
You are now connected to database "db_name" as user "my_uname".

psql=# \du
                     List of roles
 Role name |          Attributes           | Member of
-----------+-------------------------------+-----------
 rdsdb     | Superuser, Create DB         +|
           | Password valid until infinity |
 my_uname  | Superuser, Create DB          |
```

How can I fix this?

---

### Optional Info

This issue occurs because Redshift is a heavily customized fork of an old PostgreSQL version. **No user** is allowed to call `show client_min_messages`. The version of activerecord that ships with Rails 3.2.14 tries to call this function under the hood (along with a few other functions disallowed by Redshift).

I would be very surprised to find that AWS doesn't have an official workaround for Rails apps. At the moment I'm working with a version of the activerecord Postgres adapter that I modified to remove the offending code - but I would **really** rather not use this in production.

Answer (score 0):

There are redshift adapters for Rails, so it's worth to try them first.

- https://github.com/fiksu/activerecord-redshift-adapter for Rails3

  - https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-redshift-adapter
- https://github.com/aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter for Rails4

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the gem for Rails 3 and it didn't change anything. At the moment I'm trying to work with a version of activerecord that I hacked to remove the offending code. Of course, I would prefer a standard solution if anybody has one.